# QTableWidget::section:first doesn't work when only one column exists

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I've tried to create a table header, which will have a minimalistic design.
To do this, i hide all borders, except bottom border and left border for each item in header. To avoid first section left border stacking with the table border, i added `QTableWidget::section:first` setup. Here is the code:

```
QTableWidget::item {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
QTableView {
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #3B3B3B;
    background: transparent;
    selection-background-color: #D3E3ED;
    selection-color: #3B3B3B;
    margin: 1px;
    alternate-background-color: #EBEBEB
}
QHeaderView {
    font-family:'Segoe UI'; 
    font-size:12pt bold; 
    background: #EBEBEB;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    font-weight: bold; 
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
QHeaderView::section:first{
    border-left: 0px;
}

QTableView::corner { 
    background-color: transparent; 
}
```

All works well, except the situation with only one column in the table (which should be the first, the last and the only one column in the table). Than, it looks like `section:first` stops working and the section appears with left border.

[image]

But, when i add two or more columns, all normalizes again.

[image]

What's the source of this behaviour?

Is it possible to fix this behaviour with pure css, without recalling setStyleSheet in code every time the amount of columns changes?

Answer (score 0):

The assumption of `first` is that it also is the first *of many*, but you only have one section.

As explained in the [QSS reference about QHeaderView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qheaderview-widget), `:section` sub-control also supports the `only-one` [pseudo state](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states), so you need to specify the rule for *both* states.

```css
QHeaderView::section:first, QHeaderView::section:only-one {
    border-left: 0px;
}
```